# CC.NET / TFS does not delete deleted files on build server

Tags: tfs, cruisecontrol.net, tfs-power-tools

TFS is my repository, CC.NET is my build server.  If I delete a file in Visual Studio or the TFS Powertools (Windows Explorer extension), and check that delete in, I can be reasonably confident that the file will NOT be deleted off my build server.  As a result, builds often fail because of conflicting files (especially *renamed* files).

Has anybody else witnessed this behaviour?  Is there a way to ensure such changes are reflected on the build server?

Thanks;
Duncan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although we do not use TFS as source control, we do use CC.Net. As part of our build process, we clear the workspace of all files (using a Nant task) and then force a refresh of the files from our SCM.

Sounds like this would fix your problem.

Comment: I only delete files in the build-folder, but there's no reason why not to delete everything not in the root.  Good call.